# How to create a chart/plot solution works on PC and iPad

Tags: iphone, silverlight, flash, html, charts

We'd like to show some shiny charts/plots/tables for some business data. It targets PC browsers and iPhone/iPad.

Our team has experiences on ASP.NET, SQL Server Reporting Services, Cocoa Touch and some Silverlight.

We have done some research and here's possible solutions:

1. HTML5: not yet very standard and we are lack of experience.
2. Flash: it looks like Flash on iPhone runs on some sort of virtual machine, it's not very efficient. We have little knowledge on this too.
3. Silverlight + Cocoa Touch: it looks like MS is now giving up SL. We need two times of work on GUI if we choose this. Maybe I can write some XAML parser for iOS using UIKit and Core Animation.

So any ideas?

Comment: MS is not "giving up SL". They have just release Visual Studio SlightSwitch 2011 (generates SL apps) and SL 5 is out later this year with hardware 3D support. They are just changing their target audience (business apps and gaming).

Comment: @HiTech Magic, I thought so because [MS use HTML5 instead of SL on SkyDrive](http://techcrunch.com/2011/06/20/skydrive-silverlight-html5/), and is [stepping away from SL](http://techcrunch.com/2010/10/30/rip-silverlight-on-the-web/). Anyway, I don't think SL would ever support iOS due to some non-technical reasons.

Comment: This is some discussion about MonoTouch being supported on iOS at some point, but I will wait and see. I am just tired of seeing "Silverlight is dead" touted around the world when it is just not the case. HTML + CSS + JS is IMHO just a mess of legacy standards. SL is pure C# + .Net on both client & Server (IMHO genius) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the HTML5 route, there are a ton of great commercial and open source options available.  I think your run down of technologies was spot on, and HTML5 is probably the safest route for interop.  I've had pretty poor luck in terms of performance standing on flash for mobile app development.

If you go down the HTML5 route, flot has a nice permissive license, and has worked very well for me in the past:

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the answer is #1, HTML5.  It is the solution for things like this.

Flash is not going to work on iPad any time soon, so if that is an important target, then HTML5 is the solution.

The HTML5 canvas element is easy to learn, and is the future.

If you really do not want to use it, then a non-dynamic solution could be used.  Create the graphics on the server and display them.  You might check out something like imagemagick

[ImageMagick & Pie Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430018/imagemagick-pie-charts)
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=12653

Answer (score 1):

What about SVG ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)? it's good enough for charting and already working on PC/IPad/iPhone. There are a lot of development tools too.

Comment: SVG does not look like a programming language to me, is it just some kind of image?

Comment: It's XML like html describing two-dimensional vector graphics, both static and dynamic (i.e. interactive or animated). You can embed it in HTML like flash and silverlight. Believe it or not, it is close to common practice when you are talking about charting/plotting.